# PHPStorm and Typescript 0.9.1

Tags: boolean, syntax-error, typescript, phpstorm

I have updated TypeScript to the latest version (0.9.1) where type `bool` has been changed to `boolean`. The compiling works as expected but *PHPStorm 6.0.3* complains that `boolean` is "unresolved type", and gives me red squiggly lines in `ts-files`.

Is this error reporting build into PHPStorm, or does it infere it from some of the TypeScript stuff? Basically: is there anyway to fix this? I've tried installing/deleting the node package with *Typescript*, and also restarting PHPStorm but the errors still appear. It basically doesn't stop me from using *TS*, it's just a nuisance when I work.

Anybody else experienced this, or have any tips or suggestions?

Comment: Planned for 7.0, follow http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8250 for progress.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep an eye on any updates from JetBrains.

Answer (score 1):

Download and use webstorm EAP : http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP which supports TS 0.9.x